# org.hsqldb.HsqlException: user lacks privilege or object not found: ACCOUNT

Tags: hibernate, unit-testing, hsqldb

I'm trying to test DAO layer using `HSQLDB` and `Hibernate`. I've found some example that works just fine independently. But when I try to use this approach in my project I get an `exception`.
Here are configurations. Main configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa" xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/task http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa-1.3.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
    <mvc:resources mapping="/webjars/**"
        location="classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/" />
    <context:annotation-config />

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.cb.yoki.controller">
        <context:exclude-filter type="annotation"
            expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller" />
    </context:component-scan>

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.cb.yoki" />

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">
        <property name="messageConverters">
            <list>
                <bean
                    class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter" />
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.cb.yoki.entity" />
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
                <property name="showSql" value="false" />
            </bean>
        </property>
        <property name="jpaPropertyMap">
            <map>
                <entry key="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect" />
                <entry key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
                <entry key="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
            </map>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

    <jpa:repositories base-package="com.cb.yoki.repositories" />

    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/yoki" />
        <property name="username" value="root" />
        <property name="password" value="root" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Test configuration:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd">

   <import resource="application-context.xml"/>

   <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
      <property name="driverClassName" value="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver" />
      <property name="url" value="jdbc:hsqldb:mem:howtodoinjava" />
      <property name="username" value="sa" />
      <property name="password" value="" />
   </bean>

</beans>
```

This is my entity class(getters and setters omitted):

```
@Table(name="account")
@Entity
public class Account extends DomainBase implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "username", length = 50, unique = true)
    private String username;

    @Column(name = "password", length = 100)
    private String password;

    @Column(name = "firstname", length = 50)
    private String firstname;

    @Column(name = "lastname", length = 50)
    private String lastname;

    @Column(name = "email", length = 50)
    private String email;

    @Column(name = "enabled")
    private Boolean enabled;

    @Column(name = "lastpasswordresetdate")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date lastPasswordResetDate;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "user_authority",
            joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "authority_id", referencedColumnName = "id")})
    private List<Authority> authorities;

    @Column(name = "authority")
    private String authority;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "account")
    private List<Order> orders;
```

Here is test class itself:

```
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.test.annotation.Rollback;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;

@ContextConfiguration(locations = "classpath:application-context-test.xml")
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class AccountDaoTest {
    private Account account;

    @Autowired
    private AccountDao dao;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        account = new Account();
        account.setId(new Long(555555));
        account.setUsername("username");
        account.setPassword("password");
        account.setEmail("email@email.com");
    }

    @Test
    @Transactional
    @Rollback(true)
    public void addAccountTest() {
        dao.add(account);
        assertEquals(1, dao.getAll().size());
        Account extracted = dao.getAll().get(0);
        assertEquals(new Long(55555), extracted.getId());
        assertEquals("username", extracted.getUsername());
        assertEquals("password", extracted.getPassword());
        assertEquals("email@email.com", extracted.getEmail());
    }
}
```

Every time I'm trying to run my test, I get next stacktrace:

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not prepare statement

    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1763)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1677)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:458)
    at com.cb.yoki.daoimpl.AccountDaoImpl.getAll(AccountDaoImpl.java:29)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:333)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy60.getAll(Unknown Source)
    at com.cb.yoki.dao.AccountDaoTest.addAccountTest(AccountDaoTest.java:37)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:254)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:89)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:193)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:117)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:234)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:74)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not prepare statement
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:80)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:196)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.prepareQueryStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:160)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement(Loader.java:1884)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1861)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1838)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:909)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:354)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2553)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2539)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2369)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2364)
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:496)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:387)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:231)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1264)
    at org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:103)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:573)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:449)
    ... 48 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: user lacks privilege or object not found: ACCOUNT
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.Util.sqlException(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.Util.sqlException(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCPreparedStatement.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCConnection.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingConnection.prepareStatement(DelegatingConnection.java:281)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolingDataSource$PoolGuardConnectionWrapper.prepareStatement(PoolingDataSource.java:313)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$5.doPrepare(StatementPreparerImpl.java:162)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:186)
    ... 65 more
Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: user lacks privilege or object not found: ACCOUNT
    at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.SchemaManager.getTable(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.readTableName(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.readTableOrSubquery(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadTableReference(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadFromClause(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadTableExpression(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadQuerySpecification(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadSimpleTable(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadQueryPrimary(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadQueryTerm(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadQueryExpressionBody(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadQueryExpression(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.compileCursorSpecification(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserCommand.compilePart(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserCommand.compileStatement(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.Session.compileStatement(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.StatementManager.compile(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.Session.execute(Unknown Source)
    ... 71 more
```

So I can't understand what is the problem. Maybe it can't populate database or here is something wrong with hsqldb parameters? What is wrong here?

Comment: maybe not related but why Mysql5Inno dialect and not `org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect`?

Comment: Make sure the in-memory database isn't be inadvertently closed when the last connection ends.  Some in-memory databases need a setting to force it not to destroy the database until the JVM process ends.